# Insert/save client search/form entries into separate table prior to running code- CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I want to store the form entries into a table that will store what my users searched for, then actually execute the code on the form results.

I tried doing:

$this->Search->create();

$this->Search->save($this->data);

But I don't think it liked me using a model that doesn't belong to that controller (my guess this doesn't follow convention and fully utilize CakePHP).

The other idea I had was to create a new searches_controller, then run $this->data through the above code and redirect back to the Trips controller but it seems like that's not the optimal way of doing it either.

Any thoughts on how best to do this?

In procedural PHP, I would just do an INSERT query before.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What kind of data did you pass to the action?

Comment: Hi Nigel,  fyi, I just want to store the price and origin airport of the search, so I can use the search histories later to make changes if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that having Model which doesn't belong to the specific controller is not so bad idea.

Actually you can put this logic in the beforeFilter() of the Trips model like that:

```
class Trip extends AppModel {
   //....
   function beforeFind(){
      if($this->data){
         $search = ClassRegistry::init('Search'); //adding instance of Search model
         $search->save($this->data); //save the data
         //Do extra things if needed
      }
   }
   //....
}
```

This way you don't have "alien" model in your controllers, and utilise the recommendation "Fat Models, Skinny controllers" :)

Comment: The above didn't work for me but I want to increase my response rate so..........